# If $F(0,0)=0$ and $F(x,y)= \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}$ for $(x,y)\neq (0,0)$ then $F$ is differentiable at $(0,0)$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

> Let $F:\mathbb{R^2}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function, such as : $$F(x,y)=\begin{cases} 
>       0 & (x,y)=(0,0) \\
>       \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2} & (x,y)\neq (0,0)
>    \end{cases}$$
>
> Is $F$ differentiable at $(0,0)$?

My attempt :

Consider the limit, $\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} F(x,y)$ along the line $y=x$. The limit equals to $\frac{1}{2}$. However, $F(0,0)=0$. Hence $F$ is not continuous at $(0,0)$ which implies that $F$ isn't differentiable as well.

Is this approach okay ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok. U can also take (x,y) approach along y = mx in neighbourhood of (0,0), then $xy/(x^2+y^2) = \frac {m}{1+m^2}$. this shows limit values changes as m changes. So not continuous

Answer (score 1):

You are correct. I think that we have another view to corroborate your answer. Consider a variable change:

$$y = R sin (\theta)$$
$$x = R cos (\theta)$$
$$F(x,y) = F(R,\theta) = sin(\theta) cos(\theta) = \frac{sin(2\theta)}{2}\Rightarrow \lim _{R\rightarrow 0}F(R,\theta) = \frac{sin(\theta)}{2} \; \; \forall \;\theta\in[0,2\pi]$$
Thus, the limit doesn't converge for R and, so, F isn't differentiable.