# Differentiability of the function $f(x,y)=\begin{cases} \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}, & \text{if $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$}\\ 0, & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-verification, partial-derivative

Consider the function $f(x,y)=\begin{cases}
    \frac{xy}{x^2+y^2}, & \text{if $(x,y)\ne(0,0)$}\\
    0, & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$

***Question***:
Is it differentiable everywhere? Does it have partial derivatives everywhere?

***My attempt***:

$f$ is differentiable on $\Bbb R^2\backslash\{(0,0)\}$ because it is the ratio between two differentiable functions and the denominator doesn't vanish. Is it still the case in $(0,0)$?

If we write $x=r\cos\theta$ and $y=r\sin\theta$ then the function becomes

$\begin{cases}
    \frac{r^2\cos\theta\sin\theta}{r^2} & \text{if } r\ne0 & \\ 
    0 &\text{if } r=0
\end{cases}$ =
$\begin{cases} \cos\theta\sin\theta & 
\end{cases}$

We realize that $f$ doesn't depend on the radius, so the fact that $f(1,1)=1/2\ne-1/2=f(-1,1)$ so we can approach zero by decreasing the radius and preserving the values $1/2$ and one hand and $-1/2$ on the other. So the function is discontinuous at zero, so not differentiable.

Does it have partial derivatives everywhere?

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}=\lim_{h\to\ 0}\frac{f(h,0)}{h}=0$$
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}=\lim_{h\to\ 0}\frac{f(0,h)}{h}=0$$
So the partial derivatives exist in zero and elsewhere.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2496400/if-f0-0-0-and-fx-y-fracxyx2y2-for-x-y-neq-0-0-then-f-is

Comment: This is really a classic : https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7Bxy%7D%7Bx%5E2%2By%5E2%7D%24%2C%20differentiable&p=1

Comment: @ArnaudD. What are you referring to? The OP is very good and what is the point if it is a duplicate? All math I see here is  a duplicate of some well known result we can find in the web or on some good book. Then, what we should do here, construct an encyclopedia of well known result without and "exchange" between people? For who is intereted to learn the direct exchange of ideas and doubts is cucial. There are duplicates of 5/6 years ago. Well it suffices to link the duplicate, what is the problem on that?

Comment: @ArnaudD. If you like create an encyclopedia, let copy all the link for the good OP and answers in a wiki site and you have solved your problem with duplicates.

Comment: @ArnaudD. Moreover sometimes, when the OP is intersted to solve a problem by his own, link a duplicate is completely useless since probably the OP is looking for a hint to solve the problem by himself. In that case a good hint is the more effective answer.

Comment: @ArnaudD. And when the OP is just interested only to obtain a solution for a problem set, in taht cases give a link for a duplicate is equivalent to give a complete answer. Therefore we should eveluate the duplicate issue with more attention and not claiming "approach zero" is always good! That's not true.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you are right the function is not continuous and then it is not differentiable at $(x,y)=(0,0)$, since *differentiability $\implies$ continuity*.

Remarks:

- as a simpler alternative, to show that $f(x,y)$ is not continuos at
  the origin,  it suffices to consider the paths with $x=0$ and $x=y$.
- the existence of the partial derivative is not sufficient to guarantee differentiability indeed for that we need also that at least one partial derivative is also continuos at that point.